# Существуют ли программы для форматирования исходников?

Tags: c++, синтаксис

Дело в том, что, заглядывая в чужой исходник с кривым форматированием, теряюсь в догадках, что это такое. Сам свой стиль отточил, а вот с чужими кодами прямо беда какая-то. Может, их прогонять через что-то надо перед чтением?

Comment: Много их, хороших и разных. Я обычно пользуюсь indent'ом.

Comment: @alexlz дайте пожалуйста ссылочку, сам не нашел прогу под таким именем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел, это `SourceFormatX`.

Comment: Windows only, да ещё и за бешеные деньги... Странный выбор при наличии огромного количества бесплатных кроссплатформенных решений :)

Answer (score 1):

Вообще форматирование кода это стандартная функция приличного IDE. Что Eclipse, что Intellij IDEA умеют это делать. Более того, они умеют в настройках сохранять стиль форматирования и в зависимости от конкретной ситуации применять тот или иной стиль форматирования к тому или иному исходнику.

Comment: У меня mvs.

Comment: @perfect в VS тоже есть механизм изменения стиля кодирования, правда, не такой мощный как в других IDE. Посмотри [это видео](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UHGyD_YAcs4).